# Getting stdin into the Powershell stream

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The following script works well when the filename is specified on the command line.

tail.bat

```
@echo off
set "COUNT=%1"
set "COUNT=%COUNT:-=%"
set "FILENAME=%~2"
powershell "Get-Content %FILENAME% -Last %COUNT%"
```

However, what I need is to be able to pipe the text into `Get-Content` from stdin. I would like to write the following to get the last three Subversion tags assigned to the project. What can I do to get the source to `Get-Content` to be stdin?

```
svn ls svn://ahost/arepo/aproject/tags | call tail.bat -3
```

NB: I am not permitted to install any helpful tools like `tail` from the outside. It has to be done with the programs already available on the machine.

**Update:**

@mklement0 provided the answer. From that, I added code to use a default COUNT value of 10 if it is not provided. This matches the UNIX/Linux way.

```
@echo off

SET "COUNT=%~1"
IF "%COUNT:~0,1%" == "-" (
    SET "COUNT=%COUNT:~1%"
    SHIFT
) ELSE (
    SET "COUNT=10"
)
SET "FILENAME=%~1"

if "%FILENAME%" == "" (
    powershell -noprofile -command "$Input | Select-Object -Last %COUNT%"
) else (
    powershell -noprofile -command "Get-Content \"%FILENAME%\" -Last %COUNT%"
)

EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rewrite `tail.bat` as follows:

```
@echo off

set "COUNT=%1"
set "COUNT=%COUNT:-=%"
set "FILENAME=%~2"

if "%FILENAME%"=="" (
  powershell -noprofile -command "$Input | Select-Object -Last %COUNT%"
) else (
  powershell -noprofile -command "Get-Content \"%FILENAME%\" -Last %COUNT%"
)
```

This will **make the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) read stdin input via the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input)**, if no filename argument was passed, courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902252/45375).

Example:

```
C:> (echo one & echo two & echo three) | tail.bat -2
two
three
```

Note:

- While PowerShell generally sends through the pipeline and outputs *objects of any kind*, its **interface to the outside world *invariably* involves *strings***.
- Thus, given that **`$Input`** is an *enumerator* that represents *outside* stdin input, we can be sure that it **enumerates the input text lines** (as strings) one by one, so all we need is to *select* the lines of interest, which is why piping to `Select-Object` is sufficient.
- By contrast, reading a *file* by name in PowerShell requires `Get-Content` (which, incidentally, also sends the input file's lines one by one through the pipeline, unless you also specify `-Raw`); since `Get-Content` has `tail` functionality built in, via parameter `-Tail` (and its alias `-Last`), it is all that is needed here.
- **CAVEAT**: **Character decoding on input and re-encoding on output**  is involved when PowerShell talks to the outside world:

  - If you're only ever dealing with ASCII-encoded input (single-byte characters with code points ranging between 0 - 127), you needn't worry.
  - Otherwise, prepare for a world of pain - see below for details.

---

**Character decoding/re-encoding issues:**

- Assuming that PowerShell recognizes your *input* encoding (see below), the *output* encoding is *invariably* what the *console window*'s assigned encoding is; by default, unfortunately, that is the OEM codepage (e.g., the "DOS" code page CP437 on US-English systems), reflected in PS as `[Console]::OutputEncoding`.
- Thus, with properly recognized input, if you print to the *console*, things will look OK, but if you capture the output in a *file*, you'll end up with an OEM-codepage-encoded file, which is probably undesired.
- If feasible, you could *fundamentally* set up your console windows to use your codepage (input *and* output encoding) of choice (using `chcp`), but trying to change the encoding *ad-hoc* in your script is, unfortunately, not an option.
  Note that using UTF-8 - codepage `65001` - only works if you configure your console windows to use one of the TT (TrueType) fonts.
- As written above, the set of *input* encodings that are properly recognized is unfortunately limited to the following, based on the default input encoding (which is also the OEM codepage, reflected in PS as `[Console]::InputEncoding`; remember: input will be *re-encoded* on *output*):

  - **ASCII** input (re-encoding on output will by default preserve this encoding)
  - **UTF-16 LE input *with* a BOM** (which is what PowerShell calls `Unicode`, subject to re-encoding to something potentially different on output)
- You *could* hard-code an expected *input* encoding by adding `-Encoding <enc>` to the `Get-Content` call (which expects the Windows default codepage encoding by default), but to do the same for *stdin* input (as reflected in `$Input`) would be non-trivial.

  - E.g., with the default input encoding, if you explicitly wanted to interpret the input as UTF-8 (again, note that on *output* `[Console]::OutputEncoding` encoding is applied):
    `powershell -noprofile -command "$Input | % { [text.encoding]::utf8.GetString([Console]::InputEncoding.GetBytes($_)) } | Select-Object -Last %COUNT%"`

Comment: Thank you. I have learning to do about `$Input` as well as `Select-Object vs. Get-Content`.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I am familiar with encoding issues since I was making DOS and Windows programs run on Japanese machine before Unicode existed. Lot's of fun.