# Read raw stdin write raw stdout

Tags: powershell, encoding, binary, stdout, stdin

I'm looking for a way to read bytes from stdin and pass them to stdout. I've found this question which talks about how to read from stdin using text encoding. I want read and write using raw or binary encoding.

[Getting stdin into the Powershell stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667584/getting-stdin-into-the-powershell-stream)

The question says it is non-trival to deal with decoding and encoding. If it helps this is the way I am doing this in VBScript:

```vb
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.StdOut.Write(WScript.StdIn.Read(1024))
Loop
```

This following does not work because the encoding is wrong. I'm using redirection just for illustrative purposes. I need to be able to read from stdin.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "$Input" <file1.exe >file2.exe
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you "need to be able to read from stdin"? From where? What doesn't work as expected when you use `$input`? Why do you need PowerShell to emulate a pipe in the first place?

Comment: I want to copy a binary file from Linux to Windows. I am using a winrs type client to connect and execute a remote command on the Windows system. My Linux pipeline is "cat binary-file | winrs-client-program remote-host "cscript //nologo copy.vbs >binary-file". This requires having the VBScript file already on the remote system. I'd rather do this with one power shell command line using the -command option. I need $Input to do raw or binary encoding.

Comment: `smbclient -U user%pass //host/share --directory some/path "put 'your.file'"`?

Comment: I can not use smbclient and the destination is not shared. I need to use the winrs client. How can I perform the equivalent of that VBScript using powershell with raw or byte encoding.

Comment: `powershell -NoProfile -Command $i = [Console]::OpenStandardInput(); $o = [Console]::OpenStandardOutput(); $i.CopyTo($o); $i.Close(); $o.Close()`